# Pyspark / Redis - Data aggregation over time

Tags: python, apache-spark, redis, pyspark, spark-redis

I am streaming a lot of data (200k + events / batch of 3sec)  from **Kafka** using **KafkaUtils** Pyspark implementation.

I receive **live** data with :

- a `sessionID`
- an `ip`
- a `state`

What I am doing for now with a basic **Spark**/**Redis** implementation is the following:

**Spark job :**

- aggregate the data by `sessionID` : `rdd_combined =  rdd.map(map_data).combineByKey(lambda x: frozenset([x]), lambda s, v: s | frozenset([v]), lambda s1, s2: s1 | s2)`
- create a `set` of the different `state` ( that could be 1, 2, 3...)
- keep the `ip` information to then transform it into a `lon`/`lat`.
- check if the `sessionID` is in Redis, if **yes** updates it else writes it to Redis.

Then I run a small script **only for Redis** in Python that checks if there is a 1 in the state :

- if **yes**, the event is published in a channel (say `channel_1`) and deleted from Redis.
- if not we check / update a timestamp. If `NOW() - timestamp > 10 min` the data is published in `channel_2` or else we do nothing.

**Question :**

I keep wondering what would be the best implementation to compute most of the work with **Spark**.

- using `window` + an aggregation or `reduceByKeyAndWindow` : my fear is that if I use a window of 10 minutes and do the computation every 3secs over the *almost same data* it is not very efficient.
- using `updateStateByKey` seems interesting but the data is never deleted and this could become problematic. Also how could I check we are past the 10 minutes ?

Any thoughts on this implementation or others that could be possible ?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html)